# Bootstrap Modal - show on page load and hide with cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cookies, modal-dialog

I have a Boostrap modal with a don't show this again checkbox.

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="dismiss" />Don't show again!</label><br />
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Skip</button>
</div>
```

my modals id = `#myModal`

I have the modal showing up on page load. However I would like it to know if the user has checked the don't show again checkbox, if so not to show again.

I'm using this js code. Along side cookie.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myModal').modal();
    $('#myModal').on('hidden', function () {
        var status = $("input[name=dismiss]", this).is(":checked");
        $.cookie('modal_dismiss', status, {
            expires: 7,
            path: '/'
        });
        $("#debug").html("Value for Cookie is: " + status);
    });
});'
```

Note that in morzilla the checkbox is remembering that it has been selected but isn't stoping the modal from loading on page load.

Please help? :)

Comment: You don't seem to actually be reading the cookie value anywhere, you're only writing to it.

Comment: How would I go about reading the cookie value within the js?